# java library for email validation rfc5322 no regex

Tags: java, email-validation, hibernate-validator

Need help on email validation using java which should follow the RFC5322 specification, is there any  library implemented this feature , i am not looking for regex pattern looking for inbuild library.

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5322

Answer (score 0):

You can use email validator provided by Apache http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-validator/apidocs/org/apache/commons/validator/routines/EmailValidator.html

Corresponding maven dependency is as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.0</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
```

Comment: is this implemented using rfc5322 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, No.